# How can i dispatch an action from a helper function in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a `helper.js` file which contains all the helper function including the HTTP request handler with axios. Here are my `helper.js` file codes:

```
const HTTPRequest = (path, body, method = 'POST', authorizedToken = null) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let headers = {
            'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
        };

        // Set authorization token
        if (authorizedToken) {
            headers['Authorization'] = "JWT " + authorizedToken;  // Here i want to get user token from the redux store not though passing the token

        }

        const fulHeaderBody = {
            method,
            headers,
            timeout: 20,
            url: path
        };


axios(fulHeaderBody).then(response => {
            if (response.success) {
                resolve(response);
            } else {

                // Show toast about the error
                Toast.show({
                    text: response.message ? response.message : 'Something went wrong.',
                    buttonText: 'Okay',
                    type: 'danger'
                });
                resolve(response);
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            if (error.response) {

               if(error.response.status === 401){
                    // I WANT TO DISPATCH AN ACTION HERE TO LOGOUT CLEAR ALL STORAGE DATA IN REDUX AND CHANGE THE STATE TO INITIAL
               }else{
                    console.log('Error', error.message);
               }
            }  else {
                // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
                console.log('Error', error.message);
            }
            console.log(error.config);
            reject(error);
        })
    });
};
export default HTTPRequest;
```

Now then, the problem I am facing is that, how can I dispatch an action from this helper function or how can I get `user token` from the redux store.

I have tried creating an action name in `action.js` like this

```
export function helloWorld() {
    console.log('Hello world has been dispatched');
    return function(dispatch){
        dispatch(helloWorldDispatch());
    }
}
function helloWorldDispatch() {
    return {
        type: 'HELLO_WORLD'
    }
}
```

and in the reducer :

```
switch (action.type) {
    case 'HELLO_WORLD': {
        console.log('Hello world Current state',state);
        return state
    }
    default:
        return state
}
```

And calling it from `helper.js` like this

inside `HTTPRequest` function

```
helloWorld();
```

I can see only the log `Hello world has been dispatched`, but I don not see any log from the dispatcher.

Can anyone please tell how can I handle this. ?

Comment: @WillJenkins, what you mean I need to hand it to my helper? And how can I refer to the `dispatch`? I do not understand I m new to redux.

Comment: calling `helloWorld()` returns a function that accepts the dispatch function. You need to hand over the dispatch function to the helper method so that it can call dispatch.

Comment: @AvinKavish From where i can hand over the dispatch function? Like shall i import it from somewhere? Or shall I pass it with `HTTPRequest` at the time of calling it from the component or how can i do so ? Can you share an example it will be really helpful. ty

Comment: Passing it to `HTTPRequest` at the time of calling is the easiest and straightforward way to do it and will prevent your `HTTPRequest` from being needed to be connected to the store. This is my opinion, I'm no redux expert. This article probably has a better way to do it, https://daveceddia.com/access-redux-store-outside-react/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have already installed redux-thunk.

First you need to modify your **HTTPRequest** function in helper.js. add two more parameter to it **dispatch** as given below

```
const HTTPRequest = (path, body, method = 'POST',
                      authorizedToken = null,dispatch,actionCreator) => {
```

Then in success of your axios call you can add below line

```
 dispatch(actionCreator.success(response))
```

similarly for failure you can add as below

```
 dispatch(actionCreator.failure(error.message))
```

create an action in action.js file as

```
export const helperAction=(path, body, method = 'POST',
                      authorizedToken = null) =>{
var actionCreator = {}
actionCreator.success = helloWorld
actionCreator.failure = failureFunction //your failure action

return dispatch => {
  HTTPRequest(path, body, method = 'POST',
                      authorizedToken = null,dispatch, actionCreator)
 }
}
```

Create action creator and pass that as an argument along with dispatch to your HTTPREQUEST utility available in helper.js file. Now based upon the success and failure response it is initiating the action. using that action you can store the response in redux store and then you can use it in your component.

Updated answer below to solve exact problem. Otherwise I would recommend above solution.
 Try this

```
import store from './redux/store.js';
Const func=()=> {}

store.subscribe(func)
```

Comment: I am assuming I need to call `helperAction(<params>)` from the component right? If so it's is not dispatching any action.

Comment: It's is also dispatching an action you can check it there . It is passing dispatch as a parameter to Httprequest function.

Answer (score 2):

With the link shared by @Avin Kavish in the comment, here is my solution.

In the `helper.js` I have imported the store, and now the helper function looks like this

```
import {store} from "../redux/ConfigureStore"; //I have imported my store

const HTTPRequest = (path, body, method = 'POST', authorizedToken = false) => {
 let getInitialStates = store.dispatch(helloWorld()); //This to dispatch an action
   <ALL OTHER CODES AS ABOVE HERE>
}
```

This is because the store is an object which has few methods including dispatching an action as mention [here](https://redux.js.org/api/store).